# JMeter - viewing reports on .net application served from SSRS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, jmeter, automated-tests

I have an older aspx .net website I am testing and in some of the tests I want to view some reports. I am able to visit the report page and make selections but when I hit view report, it fails to view the report and I get a page redirect error.aspx.

Here is my test plan:

[image]

New Test Plan:

[image]

I created regular expression extractors for __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION that I also added the the post HTTP request to view the report. The parameters have all the report options and these on the bottom:

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing to be able to pull the reports? I believed they're served to the website using SSRS. I don't know if that makes a difference.

EDIT: I just noticed that it is losing the value for __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION in the request body even though I set the variable. The login and report option post http calls have a value for these parameters but then it disappears and defaults to ERROR for the view report post call.

[image]

Here are my regular expressions

[image]
[image]

EDIT: New CSS Extractors
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's HTTP Requests
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Where the issue is at
[image]

The error Response body:
[image]
[image]

Headers for the report options and report view POST HTTP requests
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're getting default values of `ERROR` because your regular expressions fail to extract the values from the response.

1. In general [using regular expressions for parsing HTML isn't recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), consider using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/) instead, example configuration would be something like:

   [image]

   See [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more information
2. I believe you should also [correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) this `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` value

Comment: I created css selector extractors for view state, event validation, and view state generator but I'm still getting the same issue. their values default to error when trying to view the report but work properly for logging in and selecting the report options. I also made css selectors for event argument and event target @dmitri-t

Comment: could it be that my "/report option" and "/report view" HTTP requests are both post requests and the variables aren't being passed correctly?